# Why is my if statement not working? i working in discord.py

Tags: python, if-statement

I am sure that I did everything right, with the help of the debugger I checked the condition and it is true, but I still can't go any further. if just doesn't work and there are no errors. All the rest of the code works perfectly.

```
spisok_ownerow = ['1166775417210937400', '1166775635591569430', '1166777377821577247', '1167003611142819860', '1170749831975813240']

@bot.command()
async def give_xp(ctx, *args):
        for id in spisok_ownerow:
            roles = ctx.message.author.roles
            for role in roles:
                if role.id == id:
                    try:
                        haves = cursor.execute(f'SELECT have FROM players WHERE name=?', (args[0],))
                        conn.commit()
                        for haves in cursor.fetchall():
                            for have in haves:
                                cursor.execute('UPDATE players SET have = ? WHERE name = ?', (have+ int(args[1]), args[0]))
                                conn.commit()
                                await ctx.send(f'{args[0]} теперь имеет {have+ int(args[1])}xp')
                                sys.exit(1)   
                    except Exception:
                        pass   
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Maybe an exception is thrown that you're completely hiding with your `except Exception: pass`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What exactly are you expecting?   What are the inputs?  What's ```spisok_ownerow```?

Comment: _if just doesn't work and there are no errors_ of course there will be no errors when you have catch all Exception in the try/except block

Comment: I checked with a debugger and it doesn't even go further than the if condition

Comment: what does it mean _doesn't even go further_?

Comment: ewokx this is a list of server admin role ids

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add input data and explain what `spisok_ownerow` is and the data it contains. Based on what you are writing, `role.id == id` is clearly not true.

Comment: buran my code doesn't work after this condition

Comment: buran and exept is after the condition, it's not even included in try, so expet is also impossible.

Comment: Then it must mean that `if role.id == id:` never matches, no?

Comment: You forgot to add what the contents of `ctx` is. Please give an example.

Comment: Cow  done, and I also checked the condition with the help of a debugger and it is true

Comment: add a `else: print(f"{role.id} != {id}"` and you should see.

Comment: How can it be true but not go further than the if condition?

Comment: Cow I'm not quite sure that I can explain it, but the data of the person who entered this command is stored from outside and I can get a list of all his roles from there and find out their id

Comment: David I'll check it out now

Comment: @maior_pain You can help us by trying to print it out and add the result here. Like Daviid already commented, you can also print out what the opposite of the if statement is.

Comment: David as a result, else is called at every if, but at the same time, if you look at the result, there is such a line 1166775635591569430 != 1166775635591569430

Comment: What I'm interested in knowing is the data types. I can see the result of `spisok_ownerow` being strings, but is that the same as the `role.id`?

Comment: Cow now I will try to change the data type in the spisok_ownerow

Comment: Cow damn, it really worked, I didn't even know that the condition wouldn't pass because of this. I was comparing a string with a int, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on troubleshooting in the comments, the solution would be:

```
spisok_ownerow = ['1166775417210937400', '1166775635591569430', '1166777377821577247', '1167003611142819860', '1170749831975813240']

@bot.command()
async def give_xp(ctx, *args):
        for id in spisok_ownerow:
            roles = ctx.message.author.roles
            for role in roles:
                if role.id == int(id):
                    try:
                        haves = cursor.execute(f'SELECT have FROM players WHERE name=?', (args[0],))
                        conn.commit()
                        for haves in cursor.fetchall():
                            for have in haves:
                                cursor.execute('UPDATE players SET have = ? WHERE name = ?', (have+ int(args[1]), args[0]))
                                conn.commit()
                                await ctx.send(f'{args[0]} теперь имеет {have+ int(args[1])}xp')
                                sys.exit(1)   
                    except Exception:
                        pass   
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: An `if` statement without an `else` clause is the core of this problem. "If condition is not met, nothing happens" has bitten me in the past many times.